# Redirect after Auth in Angular2

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

So I have a quick question. I have a login page that has some social media icons to use for logging in. What I want to achieve is that when they click the button and authorize it, they get redirected to a new page. However, what happens right now is they just remain on the /login page.

Here is my HTML, the first routerLink was my attempt at solving the issue but it just takes the user back to the home page even if they didn't complete the login process.

```
<div class="row omb_row-sm-offset-3 omb_socialButtons">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
            <a  [routerLink]="['/']" (click)="loginFacebook()" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
            <a (click)="loginTwitter()" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-twitter">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
            <a (click)="loginGoogle()" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google">
              <i class="fa fa-google"></i> Google
            </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the JS/TS code snippet for them

```
  loginGoogle(){
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider:AuthProviders.Google,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup
    });
  }
  loginFacebook(){
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup
    });
  }
  loginTwitter(){
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Twitter,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup
    });
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the AngularFire2 docs, `this.af.auth.login()` returns a Promise (technically a `firebase.Promise<FirebaseAuthState>`). You'll need to add a `.then()` clause to your `login()` call to handle successful resolution of the Promise and redirect accordingly.

Here's a rough example of how you could redirect the user back to login, assuming you're using the Angular `Router` class on your controller's `this.router`:

```
loginGoogle() {
  this.af.auth.login({
    provider:AuthProviders.Google,
    method: AuthMethods.Popup
  }).then((success) => {
    // Redirect the user back to the home page
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  });
}
```